# How does Hibernate use JDBC?

Tags: database, hibernate, jdbc

I know that Hibernate uses JDBC behind the scenes, but how does it do this/ where does it do this?

Comment: This is a legitimate question I don't see why it deserves a -1... thanks for your answer anyways

Comment: The downvote tooltip says "This question does not show any research effort", so I think it is definitely deserved.

Comment: Man, I hope I don't have to read or step through a code base as large as Hibernate's just to get a basic understanding of something.

Comment: BalusC, downloading the source code for a gigantic library like Hibernate is not a reasonable minimum for doing "research effort". Please try to be more helpful, or don't say anything at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hibernate uses JDBC to connect to the database and execute the dynamic SQL that it generates.

Hibernate is nothing more than a SQL generation engine - it uses your objects and mappings to generate SQL for you instead of making you write it by hand.

Once it does that, everything is the same as if you had written the SQL yourself.